# How to get the label to match the grid column width

Tags: wpf, listview, grid

I am making a simple leader board. What i want is to get the team name column label to be the same size as the grid column its located in.

```
<ListView x:Name="TeamList" Background="#00000000" BorderBrush="#00000000">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>

            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>

                                <!-- more columns for points -->
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="#4Fd5f4ff" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8" Background="#4Fd5f4ff">
                                <Label Width="50" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="23" FontWeight="Bold" 
            Foreground="Black">#1</Label>
                            </Border>

                            <!-- This is shortened to the size of the content -->
                            <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="#7Fd5f4ff" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8" Background="#7Fd5f4ff">
                                <Label  Height="40" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
            FontSize="19" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="20 0 0 0"
            Foreground="Black" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Label>
                            </Border>

                            <!-- More columns for points -->
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The above lists the theme name but the width of the Border/Label is shortened to the size of the actual content.

How can i get the label to expand to the size of the grid column * ?

Comment: How about using multple GridViewColumns instead of a Grid in one column?

Comment: Can you add * to gridview columns? That was why i went for a grid in the first place. I want to have the name of the team fill up remaining space and i don't know how much space that's left if the user resize the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Grid` is only sized in the `GridView` according to the size of it's content. If you turn on `ShowGridLines="True"` for your `Grid` you can see this problem immediately.

To avoid this problem, you have to give your `Grid` a width.

I looked around the the VisualTree for a `GridView` using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), and see there is no element that actually stretches to fill the max amount of space for any column in the GridView, so it doesn't appear that you can do this with a `RelativeSource` binding.

If you had a single column in your `GridView` though, you could probably get close by binding to the width of the `GridViewRowPresenter` with a `RelativeSource` binding, and using a `Converter` that removes X space from the value to account for the `Margins`

```
<Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}",
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GridViewRowPresenter}}"
    ... />
```

But a static width is probably easier if available.

Of course, if this is the only Column in your `GridView`, you would be far better served just use multiple `GridViewColumns` instead of building your own `Grid` inside a single `GridViewColumn`, like [HB said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463106/how-to-get-the-label-to-match-the-grid-column-width/16464090#comment23618560_16463106).